# Не сохраняет таблицу

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
now_date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
new_now_date = system + '\\' + now_date.replace(' ', '-') + '.xlsx'
save_workbook(excel, new_now_date)
```

Есть таблица с названием "excel". Пытаюсь её сохранить, вылетает ошибка.

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Professional\\Desktop\\Парсер hh.ru\\2019-02-08-22:14:26.562539.xlsx'`

Comment: Двоеточия в Windows вроде бы запрещены?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `:` запрошенный знак в итоговом имени `2019-02-08-22:14:26.562539.xlsx`.

Замените двоеточие например на точку:

```
new_now_date = system + '\\' + now_date.replace(' ', '-').replace(':', '.') + '.xlsx'
```

---

*Примечание:*

Красивее и безопаснее использовать `os.path` тоже для соединения пути и имя файла:

```
new_now_date = os.path.join(system, now_date.replace(' ', '-').replace(':', '.') + '.xlsx')
```